# processing a binary file containing an array using python

Tags: python, list, file, binary

I am reading and extracting some numbers from 2 LARGE files, storing them in 2 lists.
Then making histograms from the stored lists.

It takes a long time to read all the files to make the 2 lists. I figured if I stored the lists in a file I could possibly reuse them without reading all the files again.

Now the lists are large too, so if I write as binary file and it contains 2 lists like…

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7..]
[a,b,c,d,e,f..]
```

How can I process this binary file and read both arrays in ?
For smaller lists when I have done that I simply stored then copied it and pasted it in the processing code as

```
x= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7..]
y=[a,b,c,d,e,f..]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).
This will save your lists to 'out.dat':

```
with open('out.dat', 'wb') as pkl_file: 
    pickle.dump([x,y], pkl_file, -1)
```

And this will load them afterwards:

```
with open('out.dat', 'rb') as pkl_file: 
    x,y = pickle.load(pkl_file)
```

So you could put in your code something like:

```
if not os.path.exists('out.dat'):
    x, y = generate_x_y() #your time consuming method
    with open('out.dat', 'wb') as pkl_file: 
        pickle.dump([x,y], pkl_file, -1)
else:
    with open('out.dat', 'rb') as pkl_file: 
        x,y = pickle.load(pkl_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle-python-object-serialization) is a good way. If you want portability, you could go for [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json).

```
import json

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

with open('saved_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump([x, y], f)    # or as a dict: json.dump(dict(x=x, y=y))

# To read it back...

with open('saved_data.json') as f:
    x, y = json.load(f)

>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> y
[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'f']
```

And another often overlooked alternative is to use [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve).

```
>>> import shelve
>>> shelf = shelve.open('saved_data.shelf')
>>> shelf
{}
>>> shelf['x'] = x
>>> shelf['y'] = y
>>> shelf
{'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
>>> shelf.close()

>>> shelf = shelve.open('saved_data.shelf')    # reopen shelf
>>> shelf['x']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> shelf['y']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```